# PHP: preg_match_all() - divide an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I have the following code:

```
$str = '{"ok1", "ok2"}, 
        {"ok3", "ok4"}, 
        {"ok5", "ok6"}';

preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

which outputs this: 
`Array ( [0] => ok1 [1] => ok2 [2] => ok3 [3] => ok4 [4] => ok5 [5] => ok6 )`

It works perfect but I want to make it array1, array2 and array3. So it will divide the array depending on the tags inside `{}`

i.e.

```
 `array1` will be  `array("ok1", "ok2")`;
 `array2` will be  `array("ok3", "ok4")`; 
 `array3` will be  `array("ok5", "ok6")`;
```

Comment: Isn't that JSON? Why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php?

Comment: I am taking out a structure from the database that I wrote like this, I had no idea JSON did the same order. Do you have any idea how to make it work with either php or json with different arrays as stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of an overkill, but you could *indeed* achieve it with two regular expressions as well (if this is not some `JSON` code):

```
<?php 
$string = '{"ok1", "ok2"}, {"ok3", "ok4"}, {"ok5", "ok6"}';
$regex = '~(?<=}),\s~';
$result = array();
$parts = preg_split($regex, $string);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    preg_match_all('~"(?<values>[^"]+)"~', $part, $elements);
    $result[] = $elements["values"];
}
echo $result[0][1]; // ok2
?>
```

Comment: I tried the code and it does indeed output the arrays you mentioned, but when I do $elements["value"][0], it outputs "ok1ok3ok5". But if you have a better and easier example and a fix to this since I want to pull information out for each array, that would be great man. And thank you anyway! EDIT: easy as in your explaination that it could be achieved by two regular expressions :)

Comment: @J.Doe: See my updated answer, all values are in `$result` now.

Comment: People like you brighten StackOverFlow, keep it going brother! and thank you :)

Comment: @J.Doe: No worries, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Jan's answer is very good and I am only posting mine here as a different way to approach the problem using regex - not to take away from his answer.

If you had a string like this:

```
$output_array = array();
$str = '{"ok1", "ok2", "ok9", "ok11"}, 
        {"ok3", "ok4"}, 
        {"ok5", "ok6", "ok99"}';
```

Then you could look for all sets of curly braces and store those into an array:

```
preg_match_all('~\{.*?\}~', $str, $matches);
```

Finally, just loop through each set of braces and match each set of data appearing in quotation marks.  Then add those matches to your output array.

```
foreach ($matches[0] AS $set) {
    preg_match_all('~".*?"~', $set, $set_matches);
    $output_array[] = $set_matches[0];
}

print_r($output_array);
```

That will give you an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "ok1"
            [1] => "ok2"
            [2] => "ok9"
            [3] => "ok11"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "ok3"
            [1] => "ok4"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "ok5"
            [1] => "ok6"
            [2] => "ok99"
        )

)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but thank you for the code, appreciated mate!